# XPages: OnClick of TabPanel

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

I have a tabbed panel on my xpage and what I want to achieve is If user switches tab then current tab data should be saved for that I have written code on onClick of tabPanel, but this stops any further server-side code to run.

Sample code:

```
<xp:tabbedPanel id="tabbedPanel1">
   <xp:tabPanel label="Tab1" id="tabPanel1">
     <xp:label id="label1" value="Good Morning"></xp:label>
   </xp:tabPanel>
   <xp:tabPanel label="Tab2" id="tabPanel2">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
     <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:print("Click on Tab2");}]>
      </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
     <xp:label id="label2" value="Good Afternoon"></xp:label>
   </xp:tabPanel>
   <xp:tabPanel label="Tab3" id="tabPanel3">
    <xp:label id="label3" value="Good Evening"></xp:label>
   </xp:tabPanel>
</xp:tabbedPanel>
```

Problem: After clicking on tabPanel2 (which has onClick event code) server side stops responding and even tab switch stops.

Thanks.

Comment: I duplicated the issue, but your code has a missing closing square bracket, "]", on the <xp:this.action> line. should be: <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:print("Click on Tab2");}]]></xp:this.action>

Answer (score 1):

I know this a bit wired solution but try, invoking the save from ClientSide using the jsonRpcService.

So you can add one function to every tap onClick event on client side wich will not block the ServerSide tabbing funktions.

```
<xp:text value="#{viewScope.save}"></xp:text>

<xp:tabbedPanel id="tabbedPanel1" selectedTab="tabPanel1">
    <xp:tabPanel label="Tab1" id="tabPanel1"
        onclick="saveDokumentHelper.save();">
        <xp:label id="label1" value="Good Morning"></xp:label>
    </xp:tabPanel>
    <xp:tabPanel label="Tab2" id="tabPanel2"
        onclick="saveDokumentHelper.save();">
        <xp:label id="label2" value="Good Afternoon"></xp:label>
    </xp:tabPanel>
    <xp:tabPanel label="Tab3" id="tabPanel3"
        onclick="saveDokumentHelper.save();">
        <xp:label id="label3" value="Good Evening"></xp:label>
    </xp:tabPanel>
</xp:tabbedPanel>

<xe:jsonRpcService id="jsonRpcService1"
    serviceName="saveDokumentHelper" state="true">
    <xe:this.methods>
        <xe:remoteMethod name="save">
            <xe:this.script><![CDATA[currentDocument.save();
viewScope.put("save","saved");]]></xe:this.script>
            </xe:remoteMethod>
        </xe:this.methods>
    </xe:jsonRpcService>
```

Remember its just a possibility that came to my mind it may have some problems. I have only tested it with the viewScope variable and it works. I have not tested it with the Document.save methode yet.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good. Will try and let you know. Thanks again.